# Regular expression to capture from a character until the first period

Tags: regex

My regex string looks something like

**Your order #Q-111-111-1111. Bill amount is $100.50**

How can I extract order number i.e. string between '#' and first '.'

**Q-111-111-1111**

I've tried:

```
/#(.*[^.])[.].+?/
```

But it's capturing upto the last dot character. I'm sure, I need to use non greedy matching but I'm unable to accomplish that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the following regex:

```
#(.*?)\.
```

`*` is *greedy* - it causes the engine to repeat the preceding token as often as possible, when you append `?` to `.*`, it'll be *lazy* (ungreedy), and will match until the first dot.

To demonstrate it, lets take an example:

- `#(.*)\.` applied on #12-34.234-3.234. hello world

  `.*` will first match everything until the end of the string (`d` character), then it'll try to match dot, but it doesn't exist, so it'll keep backtracking untill it matches `4`, then the dot is found, matched string is `#1234.2343.234`
- `#(.*?)\.` applied on #12-34.234-3.234. hello world

  `.*?` will match only until `4`, then the dot is found and will be matched, the laziness causes it to stop searching for more tokens to consume

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
/#([^.]*)\./
```

With `[^.]*` you match a sequence of anything but a dot (no need to escape dot inside brackets) followed by a dot. The result you want is in the first group. For example in javascript:

```
/(?:#)([^.]*)(?=\.)/.exec("#Q-111-111-1111.")[1]
```

returns

```
Q-111-111-1111
```

If you don't want to make use of groups the following regular expression can be applied (not for javascript unfortunately as it doesn't support positive lookbehinds):

```
/(?<=#)[^.]*(?=\.)/
```

Answer (score 3):

Something restrictive will avoid false positive results:

```
(#[A-Z](-\d+){3})
```

This one will match string build of `#` followed by 1 capital letter and 3 group of digit starting by `-`.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/pV6sH2/4).

I prefer to not use the final `.` because you may want to parse strings like those:

> Your order #Q-111-111-1111 as been sent.
>
> Following your order #Q-111-111-1111, we will never call you back and you will never see your money again.

You can be even more restrictive and match only strings with the good amount of digits:

```
#([A-Z])-(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})
```

A good thing is that every relevant part is now in a different group.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/tC7pW3/2).